# Sigma algebra unequal to its universal completion

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. The completion of $\mathcal{F}$ w.r.t. $P$ is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains $\mathcal{F}$ and all subsets of $P$-nullsets in $\mathcal{F}$. The universal completion is defined as the intersection of all universal completions of $\mathcal{F}$ w.r.t all probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.
What is a (as minimal as possible) working example of a sigma-algebra that differs from its universal completion.

Comment: Perhaps the $\sigma$-algebra of the Borel sets?

Comment: What set is in $\mathcal{F}$ but not in the universal completion?

Comment: As far as I know, the non-Borel sets in the completion (with respect to Lebesgue measure) cannot be explicitly described. We know they exist because the cardinality of all Borel sets is $\mathfrak c$, whereas the cardinality of null sets is $2^{\mathfrak c}$, as the Cantor set has cardinality $\mathfrak c$ and all of its subsets are null.

Comment: But what about the universal completion? I have seen a proof of the existence of Lebesgue but non Borel sets here on SE, but I don't see how it helps in the case of universal completions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Example:** Let $\Omega$ be the space of continuous functions mapping $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$. When endowed with the uniform norm, $\Omega$ is a Banach space. The Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ coincides with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the projection maps $\Omega\ni f\to f(t)\in\Bbb R$, $t\in [0,1]$. It is known ["The set of continuous nowhere differentiable functions,"
*Pacific J. Math.* **83** (1979) 199–205] that the subset $M\subset\Omega$ comprising the nowhere differentiable elements of $\Omega$ is not a Borel set but is *co-analytic* (that is, the complement of an analytic subset of $\Omega$). Thus, because analytic sets are universally measurable, $M$ is universally measurable.