# Disintegration theorem: how do the authors prove that $\mu_y$ is supported on $\pi^{-1} (y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, polish-spaces

Recently, I came across Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/02/04/254a-lecture-9-ergodicity/#more-252) about disintegration theorem.

> **Disintegration theorem** Let
>
> - $X$ be a Polish space, $\mathcal X$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, and $\mu$ a Borel probability measure on $X$.
> - $(Y, \mathcal Y)$ be a measurable space and $\pi:X\to Y$ a measurable map.
> - $\nu := f_\sharp \mu$ be the push-forward of $\mu$ by through $f$.
>
> Then there is a collection $(\mu_y)_{y\in Y}$ of Borel probability measures on $X$ with the following properties.
>
> 1. For all bounded measurable $f:X\to \mathbb C$, the map
>    $$
>    y \mapsto \int_X f\mathrm d\mu_y
>    $$
>    is measurable.
> 2. For all bounded measurable $f:X\to \mathbb C$ and $\nu$-integrable $g:Y\to \mathbb C$,
>    $$
>    \int_X f (g\circ \pi) \mathrm d\mu = \int_Y \left(\int_X f\mathrm d\mu_y\right)g(y)\mathrm d\nu(y). \quad (\star)
>    $$
> 3. For all bounded measurable $g:Y\to \mathbb C$, for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$,
>    $$
>    g\circ \pi = g(y) \quad \mu_y\text{-a.e.} \quad (\star\star)
>    $$

At page 80 of Dellacherie/Meyer's *Probabilities and Potential*, the authors prove further that

> if $Y$ is a separable metric space and $\mathcal Y$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mu_y$ is supported on $\pi^{-1} (y)$ for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$.

Their reasoning is as follows, i.e.,

> Let $(\mu_y)_{y\in Y}$ be the family obtained by above theorem. Let $G := X \times Y$ and $\mathcal G$ its product Borel $\sigma$-algebra. We define a map
> $$
> \phi : X \to G, x \mapsto (x, \pi (x)).
> $$
> Let $\lambda := \phi_\sharp \mu$ be the push-forward of $\mu$ through $\phi$. Then
> $$
> \lambda (B) = \int_Y (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (B) \mathrm d \nu (y) \quad \forall B \in \mathcal G.
> $$
> Let $K$ be a countable union of compact subsets of $X$ that supports $\mu$; $K$ is obviously Lusin, so $\phi (K)$ is Souslin and hence universally measurable in $G$, and finally it supports $\lambda$. We deduce that for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$, $\mu_y$ is supported by the section $K_y$ of $\phi(K)$ by $y$ and this is contained in $\pi^{-1} (y)$.

It seems to me

- *"...universally measurable in $G$..."* means that $\phi(K)$ is Borel in $G$, i.e., $\phi(K) \in \mathcal G$, and
- *"...finally it supports $\lambda$..."* means that $\lambda (\phi (G)) = 1$.

However, I could not understand the sentence

> We deduce that for $\nu$-a.e. $y \in Y$, $\mu_y$ is supported by the section $K_y$ of $\phi(K)$ by $y$ and this is contained in $\pi^{-1} (y)$.

Could you explain the reasoning behind it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Universally measurable means something else. D&M list it in the index.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker From page 31, it seems *"...universally measurable in $G$..."* means that $\phi(K)$ is a set in the universal completion $\mathcal G_U$ of $\mathcal G$. So *"...finally it supports $\lambda$..."* means that $\hat \lambda (\phi(K)) = 1$ where $\hat \lambda$ is the extension of $\lambda$ to $\mathcal G_U$.

Comment: Yes, the rest is how you can leverage the (universal) measurability of the graph to get the conclusion.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker the "leverage" you mentioned is where I got stuck. Could you elaborate more on that?

Comment: Together, $\mu$ and $\pi$ give you a measure on the product $X\times Y$. A disintegratation is simply another way to define this measure. Let $G^C$ be the complement of the graph. This set must have measure zero, and, therefore must every $y$-section.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I have posted my understanding as below answer. Could you check if I understand your ideas correctly?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(\mu_y)_{y\in Y}$ be the family obtained by above theorem. Let $G := X \times Y$ and $\mathcal G$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra generated by the product topology. We define a map
$$
\phi : X \to G, x \mapsto (x, \pi (x)).
$$

Let $\lambda := \phi_\sharp \mu$ be the push-forward of $\mu$ through $\phi$. Then
$$
\lambda (C) = \int_Y (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (C) \mathrm d \nu (y) \quad \forall C \in \mathcal G.
$$

Notice that $\mathcal G$ [coincides with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248032/is-product-of-borel-sigma-algebras-the-borel-sigma-algebra-of-the-product-of) $\mathcal X \otimes \mathcal Y$, so the product measure $\mu_y \otimes \delta_y$ is compatible with $\mathcal G$. Let $K$ be a countable union of compact subsets of $X$ that supports $\mu$; $K$ is Lusin and thus Suslin.

> **Suslin-Lusin theorem (page 49)** Let $\left(E, \mathcal E \right)$ and $\left(F, \mathcal{F}\right)$ be separable metric spaces together with their Borel $\sigma$-algebras. Let $h:E \to F$ be injective measurable. If $E$ is Suslin, then $h$ is a Borel isomorphism of $E$ onto $h(E)$.

By **Suslin-Lusin theorem**, $H := \phi (K)$ is Suslin.

> **Lemma (page 48)** Let $\left(F, \mathcal F \right)$ be a separable metric space together with its Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If $B \subset E$ is Suslin, then $B$ is analytic.

Notice that $G$ [is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244427/proving-separability-of-the-countable-product-of-separable-spaces-using-density). By **Lemma**, $H$ is analytic in $G$. Let $\hat{\mathcal G}$ be the [universal completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836973/sigma-algebra-unequal-to-its-universal-completion) of $\mathcal G$ and $\hat \lambda$ the unique extension of $\lambda$ from $\mathcal G$ to $\hat{\mathcal G}$. It is mentioned [here](https://planetmath.org/analyticset1) that measurable sets are analytic, and all analytic sets are universally measurable. So $H\in \hat{\mathcal G}$. Clearly, $\hat \lambda (H) = 1$. [Then there is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure#Construction_of_a_complete_measure) $M \in \mathcal G$ such that $M \subset H$ and $\lambda(M)= 1$. We have
$$
1=\int_Y (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (M) \mathrm d \nu (y).
$$

It follows that
$$
 (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (M) = 1 \quad \nu\text{-a.e.} 
$$

Let $M_y := \{x \in X \mid (x, y) \in M\}$. By Fubini's theorem, $M_y \in \mathcal X$ and
$$
\begin{align}
 (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (M) &= \int_X \int_Y 1_{M} (x, z) \mathrm d \delta_y (z) \mathrm d \mu_y (x) \\
 &= \int_X 1_{M_y} (x) \mathrm d \mu_y (x) \\
 &= \mu_y (M_y).
 \end{align}
$$

It follows that
$$
\mu_y (M_y) = 1 \quad \nu\text{-a.e.} 
$$

Notice that $M_y \subset \pi^{-1} (y)$. This completes the proof.

---

**Update:** Below I prove the equality involving $\lambda$. For $C \in \mathcal G$, we define a map
$$
f_C: y \to \mathbb R, y \mapsto (\mu_y \otimes \delta_y) (C) .
$$

Let $\mathcal C := \{A\times B \mid A \in \mathcal X, B \in \mathcal Y\}$ and $\mathcal D := \{ C \in \mathcal G \mid f_C \text{ is measurable}\}$. If $C = A\times B \in \mathcal C$, then
$$
f_C (y) = \left ( \int_X 1_A \mathrm d \mu_y \right ) 1_B(y).
$$

By **(1.)**, $y \mapsto \int_X 1_A \mathrm d \mu_y$ is measurable. As such, $f_C$ is measurable for all $C \in \mathcal C$. This implies $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal D$. Clearly, $\mathcal C$ is a $\pi$-system. Let's prove that $\mathcal D$ is a $\lambda$-system. Clearly, $X \times Y \in \mathcal D$. If $C \in \mathcal D$ then $f_{C^c} = 1- f_C$ is measurable and thus $C^c \in \mathcal D$. If $(C_n) \subset \mathcal D$ is pairwise disjoint, then $f_{C} = \sum_n f_{C_n}$ with $C := \bigcup_n C_n$ is measurable and thus $C \in \mathcal D$. By Dynkin's $\pi$−$\lambda$ theorem, we get $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \mathcal D$. Hence $f_C$ is measurable for every $C \in \mathcal G$.

Let $\mathcal E := \{C \in \mathcal G \mid \lambda(C) = \int_Y f_C \mathrm d \nu\}$. For $C = A \times B \in \mathcal C$. By **(2.)**,
$$
\int_Y f_C \mathrm d \nu = \int_Y \left ( \int_X 1_A \mathrm d \mu_y \right ) 1_B(y) \mathrm d \nu (y) = \int_X  1_A (1_B  \circ \pi) \mathrm d \mu = \mu(A \cap \pi^{-1} (B)).
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\lambda (C) = \mu (\phi^{-1} (C)) = \mu (A \cap \pi^{-1} (B)).
$$

As such, $\mathcal C \subset \mathcal E$. Just as above, we can prove that $\mathcal E$ is a $\lambda$-system. By Dynkin's $\pi$−$\lambda$ theorem, we get $\sigma(\mathcal C) \subset \mathcal E$. Hence $\lambda(C) = \int_Y f_C \mathrm d \nu$ for every $C \in \mathcal G$. This completes the proof.